# What is wrong with my code for Pairwise swapping of linked list in C?

Tags: c, list, linked-list, malloc, singly-linked-list

This is my code for pairswapping:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct Node{
     int data;
     struct Node *next; 
};
int main(){
struct Node *list, *head;
head = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
list = head;
int i;
for(i=0;i<6;i++){
    list->data=i;
    list->next = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    list = list->next;
 }
list->next = NULL;
list = head;
while(list->next->next!=NULL){
    int temp = list->data;
    list->data = list->next->data;
    list->next->data = temp;
    list = list->next->next;
 }
 printf("Pair swapped list: ");
 while(head->next!=NULL){
       printf("%d\n",head->data);
        head=head->next;
  }
 return 0;
}
```

I have two problems. The main is that this code is giving a runtime error, I don't see why. and second thing is that if I use list = NULL instead of list->next = null and then while(list!=NULL) then it is causing infinite loop. and if the code is kept same, a garbage element is created at end. please help me.

Comment: Unrelated to the crash, but you never initialize `list->data`, its value will be *indeterminate* and seemingly random.

Comment: [Why you should not cast the result of `malloc()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845)

Comment: As for your crash, please learn how to use a debugger, so you can step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and pointers etc.

Comment: You do not `free()` your memory. Not all OS will reclaim un-`free()`d memory at the end of `main()`.

Comment: What do you think that `list->data;` in the first loop does, why is that code there?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that i have initialized to i. it got missed out while copying the code, sorry.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the actual code, including initialization.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @TobySpeight there was no compiler warning as i was getting runtime error. that problem is solved btw, now i am dealing with the second problem i mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line causing problem is:

```
while(list->next->next!=NULL) {
```

You do not handle when `list->next` is `NULL`

So, just replace it with:

```
while(list->next != NULL && list->next->next != NULL) {
```

---

And for the second problem, as pointed by DevSolar, you must control better the list creation:

```
struct Node *list, *head, *last;
head = list = last = NULL; 

for (i=0; i<6; i++)
{
    /* create a node */
    list = malloc(sizeof *list);

    /* if head is not set, set it */
    if (NULL == head)
        head = list;

    /* fill new element */
    list->data = i;
    list->next = NULL;

    /* this new node is the child of the previous */
    if (NULL != last)
        last->next = list;     

     /* remember last created node */
    last = list;
}
```

Comment: and what about the second problem I mentioned?

Comment: @purplepsypcho but doesnt just assigning list = NULL after the loop work? wouldnt that serve the same purpose?

Comment: well i got an easier soln for the problem, i simply put a i<=5 check in the loop, so the list=list->next is not executed for last iteration and the extra node is not created.

Answer (score 1):

You have 7 nodes -- the `head`, and the 6 you create in the loop.

Your `while` checks for `list->next->next!=NULL`, and at the end of the loop you move `list` like this: `list = list->next->next;`

This means your loop runs for:

- 1st node, swapped with 2nd
- 3rd node, swapped with 4th
- 5th node, swapped with 6th.

Then `list` is set to the 7th node (with `list->next` being `NULL`). And your `while` checks for `list->next->next`. As stated, `list->next` is `NULL`, `list->next->next` is an illegal memory access (dereferencing `NULL`).

(Deferring to purplepsycho for what you *should* do -- I don't copy from other people's answers. ;-) )

Comment: now its working. but what of the second problem. how to prevent the garbage element from creating at end?

Comment: @Gameatro: The second part of your question is unclear. What should `list =  NULL` achieve? What "garbage" are you speaking of?

Comment: after the creation of list loop I have put list->next = NULL. it is creating an extra list with garbage val. but if i just write list=NULL, while printing with condition while(list!=NULL) it goes into infinity loop.

Answer (score 1):

For starters according to the C Standard the function `main` without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

In this loop

```
for(i=0;i<6;i++){
    list->data=i;
    list->next = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    list = list->next;
 }
list->next = NULL;
```

there is allocated a redundant node with an inderterminate value of the data member `data`.

The condition in this while loop

```
while(list->next->next!=NULL){
    int temp = list->data;
    list->data = list->next->data;
    list->next->data = temp;
    list = list->next->next;
 }
```

is wrong and leads to undefined behavior due to this statement at the end of the loop

```
    list = list->next->next;
```

The condition should be written like

```
while ( list && list->next )
```

Using your approach the program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next; 
};

int main(void) 
{
    struct Node *list, *head;
    const int N = 6;

    head = ( struct Node * )malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );
    list = head;

    int i = 0;
    do
    {
        list->data = i;
    } while ( ++i < N && ( list = list->next = ( struct Node *)malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) ) ) );

    list->next = NULL;

    printf("Original list: ");
    for ( list = head; list; list = list->next )
    {
        printf( "%d ", list->data );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    list = head;

    while ( list && list->next )
    {
        int temp = list->data;
        list->data = list->next->data;
        list->next->data = temp;
        list = list->next->next;
    }

    printf("Pair swapped list: ");
    for ( list = head; list; list = list->next )
    {
        printf( "%d ", list->data );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
Original list: 0 1 2 3 4 5 
Pair swapped list: 1 0 3 2 5 4
```

You can add yourself checks that malloc(s) were successfull.

A more safe program can be written using the variable `list` of the type `struct Node **`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next; 
};

int main(void) 
{
    const int N = 6;
    struct Node *head;
    struct Node **list;

    list = &head;

    for ( int i = 0; ( i < N ) && ( *list = ( struct Node *)malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) ) ); i++ )
    {
        if ( *list )
        {
            ( *list )->data = i;
            list = &( *list )->next;
        }
    }

    *list = NULL;

    printf("Original list: ");
    for ( list = &head; *list; list = &( *list )->next )
    {
        printf( "%d ", ( *list )->data );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    list = &head;

    while ( *list && ( *list )->next )
    {
        int temp = ( *list )->data;
        ( *list )->data = ( *list )->next->data;
        ( *list )->next->data = temp;
        list = &( *list )->next->next;
    }

    printf("Pair swapped list: ");
    for ( list = &head; *list; list = &( *list )->next )
    {
        printf( "%d ", ( *list )->data );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Take into account that you should free all allocated memory for the list.

And one more remark. The program does not swap nodes. It swaps values of the data member `data` of adjacent nodes.:)